# What’s the equivalent to String.localizedStringWithFormat(_:_:) for SwiftUI's LocalizedStringKey?

Tags: swift, string, localization, swiftui

What’s the equivalent to `String.localizedStringWithFormat(_:_:)` in SwiftUI?

I know `LocalizedStringKey.init(:)` can make use of string interpolation, but as I understand it this requires localizable string *keys* to be parameterized in the .strings/.stringsdict files.

This is different to how localized string keys are currently defined in the app I'm working on. Given these localizable strings in Localizable.strings:

```
"HELLO_WORLD" = "Hello, world!";
"HELLO_WORLD_PARAMETERIZED" = "Hello, %@!";
```

this works just fine in the Foundation/UIKit world:

```swift
NSLocalizedString("HELLO_WORLD", comment: "") // "Hello, world!"
String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("HELLO_WORLD_PARAMETERIZED", comment: ""), "Bob") // "Hello, Bob!"
```

But I don’t see how to make it work in SwiftUI:

```swift
let helloWorld = LocalizedStringKey("HELLO_WORLD")
Text(helloWorld) // ✅ Displays "Hello, world!" 
Text("HELLO_WORLD") // ✅ Also displays "Hello, world!" 

LocalizedStringKey("HELLO_WORLD_PARAMETERIZED", "Bob") // ❌ This won't compile, because LocalizedStringKey has no format parameter like `String.localizedStringWithFormat(_:_:)` does.

let bob = "Bob"
LocalizedStringKey("Hello, \(bob)!") //  This *would* work if the key in Localizable.strings were "Hello, %@!" – but this doesn't reflect the reality of localized string keys are currently defined for this app.

Text(verbatim: String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("HELLO_WORLD_PARAMETERIZED", comment: ""), "Bob")) //  This correctly displays "Hello, Bob!" in the Text view, but... well, it ain't pretty.
```

Do I have to change all my localizable string *keys* (as opposed to just their *values*) to be parameterized in order to be able to use them in SwiftUI views (without using the `Text(verbatim:)` workaround)?

Comment: You've already found everything's available, so nothing to add. If string not format then just use it as-is, it will be translated automatically, if you need format then only via NSLocalizedString. That's it.

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preparing-views-for-localization

Answer (score 18):

I faced this issue as well and thanks to some [sources](https://forums.swift.org/t/localize-interpolated-string-why-only-string-value-work/27528/2) and [links](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/117758) I think I got it working the expected way.

I was working on Xcode 12 Beta 6 when I succeeded, I can not confirm/infirm on other versions.

The translation key needs to reflect the interpolated string you'll use in SwiftUI in which every argument is replaced by the [String Format specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) representing the type of the argument.

In your example, you want to insert one `String` as parameter. This corresponds to the `%@` specifier.

Rewrite your `Localizable.strings` by:

```
"HELLO_WORLD" = "Hello, world!";
"HELLO_WORLD_PARAMETERIZED %@" = "Hello, %@!";
```

To use it inside a `Text`:

```
Text("HELLO_WORLD_PARAMETERIZED \(someStringVar)")
```

If you want to use a `UInt` parameter, use the `%llu` identifier, `%lld` for `Int` (see the String Format specifier link)

The same rules apply for `.stringdict`, name the key using the same pattern:

```
<dict>
    <key>%llu elements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@VARIABLE@</string>
        <key>VARIABLE</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>llu</string>
            <key>zero</key>
            <string>No elements</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>One element</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%llu elements</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

To use the key:

```
Text("\(someUIntVarValue) elements")
```

Comment: This has probably been only fixed in recent Xcode12 because it's not working in Xcode 11.5. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, it does work if I run the app, but I'm looking at making it work via Xcode Preview, which doesn't somehow

Comment: This is horrible, no one is going to rewrite all their string keys just to include the parameter in the parameter **name**. Especially since such files are usually used across platforms.

Comment: You can use NSLocalizedString or custom implementation of the localized strings if needed and do not lose environment abilities https://nonameplum.github.io/posts/SwiftUI%20custom%20localization%20strings%20handling/

Comment: Working with iOS' localization system after working in Android's much better system is so painful.

Comment: this is not working with positional arguments. eg: Hello %1$@ my name is %2$@