# LocalizedStringKey with variable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Im,trying to use LocalizedStringKey in TextField, it have variable inside, so all contruction looks like

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey("Text1 \(email) Text2"))
```

How can i translate normally text inside it? Text1 and Text2 will be always static.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62168292/what-s-the-equivalent-to-string-localizedstringwithformat-for-swiftuis-lo ?

Comment: @Larme thanks, i new this trick, but im confusing to use it between 2 strings, chained in one