# SwiftUI Text and LocalizedStringKey with parameter

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, nslocalizedstring, localizedstringkey

I am trying to add a SwiftUI localized Text with parameter. However in the whole app we use a wrapper around localization keys so we have something like this:

```
static let helloWorldText = NSLocalizedString("helloWorldText", comment: "")
```

with usage

```
label.text = LocalizationWrapper.helloWorldText
```

or

```
Text(LocalizationWrapper.helloWorldText)
```

and it works fine.

Then when it comes to adding a localized text with parameter it doesn't seems to work.

So I have a key `"helloWorld %@"`

and I have a `static let helloWorldWithParameter = NSLocalizedString("helloWorld %@", comment: "")`

now i tried to do this:

```
Text("\(LocalizationWrapper.helloWorldWithParameter) \(name)")
Text(LocalizedStringKey(LocalizationWrapper.helloWorldWithParameter + " " + name))
Text(LocalizationWrapper.helloWorldWithParameter + " " + name)
```

none of them works, however `Text("helloWorld \(name)")` works just fine.

Then i tried to remove NSLocalizedString leaving only `LocalizationWrapper.helloWorldWithParameter` as a clean string but it allso didn't do a thing

How can I make this work? I seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62168292/what-s-the-equivalent-to-string-localizedstringwithformat-for-swiftuis-lo) but it is kind of dirty.

Comment: What about using `static func helloWorldText(_ str: String) { } -> String` ? and, then `Text(LocalizationWrapper.helloWorldText(name))`?

Comment: Work fine with Text("\(LocalizationWrapper.helloWorldWithParameter) \(name)"). Are you sure you have set exact same key in .string file ```helloWorld %@```?

Comment: @RajaKishan I just checked and it is not working, here you have a screenshot https://ibb.co/bF9kwzr

Comment: @MaciejZajda if possible please attach a sample demo project.

Comment: @RajaKishan i send you an invite to repo on github

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this extension

```
extension String {
    public func localized(with arguments: [CVarArg]) -> String {
        return String(format: NSLocalizedString(self, comment: ""), locale: nil, arguments: arguments)
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
Text(LocalizationWrapper.helloWorldWithParameter.localized(with: [name]))
```

Also, This approach is correct

```
static func helloWithParameter(parameter: String) -> LocalizedStringKey {
    return "helloWorld \(parameter)"
}
```

Comment: This way you loose the `.enviroment` abilities that SwiftUI provides. But you can overcome that issue too https://nonameplum.github.io/posts/SwiftUI%20custom%20localization%20strings%20handling/