# Localizable string interpolation doesn't work as expected

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization, localizable.strings

I'm currently trying to understand why this little piece of code doesn't work as expected:

```
// ContentView.swift (before var body: some View)
let name = "Emma"

// ContentView.swift (inside var body: some View)
Text("hello-name \(name)")

// Localizable.strings
"hello-name %@" = "Hello, my name is %@";
```

I have also tried using `NSLocalizedString` as sometimes it does the trick:

```
// ContentView.swift (inside var body: some View)
Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("hello-name %@", comment: "Name"), name))
Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("hello-name %@", comment: "Name"), name as String))
Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("hello-name %@", comment: "Name"), name as CVarArg))
```

But still I don't get `Hello, my name is Emma`. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: Depends of which line I'm trying but most of the time it's `hello-name Emma`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69438979/swiftui-text-and-localizedstringkey-with-parameter ? You need to tel it's a `LocalizedStringKey` I think

Answer (score 0):

Use `"hello-name"` as the key in the strings file and the first arg to `NSLocalizedString`

Comment: I tried and the result is `hello-name`. "Emma" just don't show up in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found where was the problem! As I'm so dumb, I was filling in the wrong `Localizable.strings` file.

My app was launching in French (my first iOS language) while I was filling in the English file...

So, the code below is working very fine:

```
// ContentView.swift (before var body: some View)
let name = "Emma"

// ContentView.swift (inside var body: some View)
// They all work nicely!
Text("hello-name \(name)")
Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("hello-name %@", comment: ""), name))
Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("hello-name %@", comment: ""), name as CVarArg))

// Localizable.strings (with the good one this time)
"hello-name %@" = "Hello, my name is %@";
```

Answer (score 0):

How many Localizable.strings file you have?

try declare

```
"hello-name %@" = "Hello, my name is %@";
```

in all your language files.