# How to use interpolation with strings that rely on automatic grammar agreement?

Tags: ios, swift, string, swiftui, nslocalizedstring

I'm trying to solve a seemingly simple issue: display free trial terms to the user in SwiftUI `Text` view. I have a unit string set to `"Week"` and a `value` that I can switch from 1 to 2. To handle plurals, I'm taking advantage of automatic grammar agreement on iOS 15. I have a string ready in my `Localizable.strings` file like so:

```
"Subscription period: %lld %@" = "^[%lld ^[%@](grammar: { partOfSpeech: \"noun\" })](inflect: true)";
```

To build out the string, I **need** to use string interpolation to add the word 'free'. I know that adding the word inside strings file will solve the issue, but I don't want to do that. I want to use that string universally, not necessarily pertaining to free trials. I don't understand why I can't call some init, pass it a key, and get a plain string back that I can interpolate as I wish. I've tried a lot of ways that are showcased in the code snippet attached. Either the string is not found, or the automatic grammar agreement is not applied. There appears to be `String.LocalizationValue.StringInterpolation` struct, but I can't figure out how to use it since there is no documentation whatsoever. What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help!

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    /// This value mimics what **StoreKit 2** returns for `Product.SubscriptionPeriod.Unit` in its `localizedDescription` on iOS 15.4.
    let unit = "Week"
    
    @State var value = 1
    
    var key: LocalizedStringKey {
        "Subscription period: \(value) \(unit)"
    }
    
    var plainStringKey: String {
        "Subscription period: \(value) \(unit)"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                // Works fine without string interpolation.
                Text(key)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                
                // `NSLocalizedString` doesn't work and it shouldn't as per its docs.
                Text("\(NSLocalizedString(plainStringKey, comment: "")) free")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                
                // Doesn't see the string.
                Text("\(String(localized: String.LocalizationValue(stringLiteral: plainStringKey))) free")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                
                // This way also doesn't see the string, which is strange, because it should be just like the following way, which does see the string.
                Text("\(String(localized: String.LocalizationValue.init(plainStringKey))) free")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                
                // Sees the string (only if I pass literal, not the plainStringKey property), but doesn't apply automatic grammar agreement.
                Text("\(String(localized: String.LocalizationValue("Subscription period: \(value) \(unit)"))) free")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                
                
                // MARK: Bad solution:
                /*
                 - Doesn't work with Dynamic Type properly
                 - You have to approximate horizontal spacing
                 */
                
                HStack(spacing: 3) {
                    Text("Subscription period: \(value) \(unit)")
                        .textCase(.lowercase)
                    Text("free")
                }
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
            }
            
            Section {
                Stepper(value: $value, in: 1...2) {
                    Text("Value: \(value)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

You can download the sample project [here](https://github.com/genebogdanovich/AutomaticGrammarAgreementIssue).

Comment: Perhaps `.stringdict`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63605964/351305

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62042837/12299030?

Comment: I didn’t use stringdict because I prefer to use automatic grammar agreement. I like the idea of Apple worrying about different localizations and plurals. Not the developer.

Comment: No, Asperi, it doesn’t work. I tried your way before posting the question and now double-checked and added it to the sample project. It also shoots right through automatic grammar agreement and displays this: `^[1 ^[Week] (grammar: { partOfSpeech: "noun" })I (inflect: true) free`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was actually very close with this piece of code:

```swift
Text("\(String(localized: String.LocalizationValue("Subscription period: \(value) \(unit)"))) free")
```

But using `String(localized:)` isn't correct. I guess it's because automatic grammar agreement uses markdown, which is the prerogative of `AttributedString`. We should use `AttributedString(localized:)`. But even then, it's not going to inflect because apparently there is a bug in Foundation. But once it gets patched, it will work like a charm.

Here is the correct solution:

```swift
func freeTrialDuration() -> Text {
    // Use plain string.
    let duration: String = "^[\(value) ^[\(unit.lowercased())](grammar: { partOfSpeech: \"noun\" })](inflect: true)"
    // Use the following way to get the localized string.
    let localizedDuration = AttributedString(localized: String.LocalizationValue(duration))
    
    return Text("\(localizedDuration) free")
}
```